# SELENIUM: XPATH of the element works in window not in linux machine (ec2-**-**-\*\*.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, aws-ec2-instance-connect

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/input').send_keys(country)`

This is the xpath for sending text in the dropdown of the facebook ad library report. It works well in window but when I run this selenium script in Linux machine (ec2-**-**-**.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com) it shows error in this line:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`

``` {"method":"xpath","selector":"//body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/input"} `` ```

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--silent")
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1519.200,5471.890")
options.add_argument("--window-position=0,0")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

These are the arguments used.

Kindly given the solution for this

Comment: You really need to learn to build an Xpath on your own, these auto generated XPath's from Chrome are always going to be flaky.

Comment: xpath syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp        
cheatsheet:   https://devhints.io/xpath